# How to create a Vapor data format (.vdf) file in python?

Tags: python, file-conversion

a longer search in google didn´t help me. But is there any way to create a .vdf file (VAPOR data format) for VAPOR (don´t confuse it with valve data format)? Or at least WRF-AWE with numpy arrays?

The problem is, that we use an exotic file-format, which I would have to convert into the mentioned file-format to be able to analyse it with VAPOR.

Thank you very much.